# How to add cocoapod to ios framework

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, cocoapods

I am working on ios project, where I am using EVReflection library in project,I am having one custom framework there I am using EVReflection for that I have taken cocoapod i added after that I am trying to build framework it is not building and one more my project is also using Evreflection so if I add my custom framework to project will it add automatically import Evreflection there also.

SampleFramwork i am adding evreflection

code:

```
 platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'SampleFramework' do
   use_frameworks!
  pod "EVReflection"

end
```

Comment: did you install cocoapods ?

Comment: yes,it is importing also,but in after build still it is showing red color only

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install POD

[ 1 ] Open terminal n type:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Gem will get installed in Ruby inside System library. Or try on 10.11 Mac OSX El Capitan, type:

```
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods
```

If there is an error "activesupport requires Ruby version >= 2.xx", then install latest activesupport first by typing in terminal.

```
sudo gem install activesupport -v 4.2.6
```

[ 2 ] After complete installation, there will be a lot of messages, read them and if no error found, it means cocoapods installation is done. Next, you need to setup the cocoapods master repo. Type in terminal:

```
pod setup
```

And wait it will download the master repo. The size is very big (370.0MB at Dec 2016). So it can be a while. You can track of the download by opening Activity and goto Network tab and search for git-remote-https. Alternatively you can try adding verbose to the command like so:

```
pod setup --verbose
```

[ 3 ] Once done it will output "Setup Complete", and you can create your XCode project and save it.

[ 4 ] Then in terminal cd to "your XCode project root directory" (where your .xcodeproj file resides) and type:

```
pod init
```

[ 5 ] Then open your project's podfile by typing in terminal:

```
open -a Xcode Podfile
```

[ 6 ] Your Podfile will get open in text mode. Initially there will be some default commands in there. Here is where you add your project's dependencies. For example, in the podfile, type

```
pod 'EVReflection'
```

(this line is an example of adding the AFNetworking library to your project).

Other tips:

Uncomment platform :ios, '8.0' Uncomment user_frameworks! if you're using Swift

When you are done editing the podfile, save it and close XCode.

[ 7 ] Then install pods into your project by typing in terminal:

```
pod install
```

Depending how many libraries you added to your podfile for your project, the time to complete this varies. Once completed, there will be a message that says

```
"Pod installation complete! There are X dependencies from the Podfile and X total pods installed."
```

Now close your xcode project and open .xcworkspace xcode project file and start coding. :)

Answer (score 1):

Configuration should look something like this:

1) Open terminal and locate your project root

2) write: **pod init**

3) write: **atom podfile** *(or nano/vim/some other texteditor)*

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'

# Public spec repository
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

use_frameworks!

target 'ProjectName' do

    # Pods for ProjectName
    pod 'EVReflection'


end
```

4) write: **pod install**

5) close all of your current xcode projects, and open project.xcworkspace file

Answer (score 1):

- Use the format below in `Podfile`

  `use_frameworks!
  target "YourProjectName" do
  pod 'EVReflection'
  end`
- If it is not building yet , add it to **Embedded Binaries**  and **Linked Frameworks and Libraries**

[image]